# Checking if a pointer is 16 byte aligned

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, integer, truncation

I'm trying to compile the OpenEXR library on MingW-w64. I am getting the following compilation error as gcc complains about truncation:

```
ImfOptimizedPixelReading.h:73:50: error: cast from 'const void* __restrict__'
to 'long unsigned int' loses precision [-fpermissive]

     unsigned long trailingBits = ((unsigned long)pPointer) & 15;
                                                  ^
```

I can fix this easily on my own toolchain, for instance by casting to `uintptr_t` instead of `unsigned long`, but I cannot push this patch because it is c++11 only and thus will break compatibility with other compilers.

This function just checks if the trailing bits are all zero and return true/false

What would be the most portable way to do this while staying at least c++98 compliant? I have tested `static_cast<unsigned long>` but I just get another error.

Comment: what about *memcpy*'ing the least significant byte ?

Comment: How about `unsigned long long` ?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for [std::alignof](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignof) / [std::alignas](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/alignas) ...?

Comment: @JesperJuhl but the OP wants a c++98 solution ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Unfortunately, depending on endianess, the least significant byte maybe 0 or 7...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Sure, you are right, but that's their loss. Better solution than being stuck in the stone-age would be to get with the program and use modern C++.

Comment: @JesperJuhl : yes, but saying that to the developpers of a nice opensource library which is an industry standard, while it's the first time you contact them and contribute to the project, is rude, and unfeasible. I have to stick to c++98 in order to make my patch accepted. That library is developped by ILM and used everyday by ILM, Weta Digital, DreamWorks, Pixar, etc...